# Ajax post to a web server issue

Tags: ajax, jquery, jquery-mobile, post

Hey everyone Im having some issues with my ajax post to a web server. This is coming from a mobile app Ive been tinkering with and I'm not certain why the post is not working.

Here is the code:

```
    var username = window.localStorage.getItem("username");
    var url = "https://website.com/webservices/service.do?&username=" + username + "&accept=1&isMobile=1";
    console.log(url);
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    async: false,
                    url: url,
                    success: Success(), 
                    error: Fail(e)
                   });
        })
```

The last item I see in my debug is the url from the log: 
( https://website.com/webservices/service.do?&username=test&accept=1&isMobile=1 )
When I copy that url and paste it into a web browser the post works and the service updates the database like its suppose to. Does anyone have any ideas what could be happening to my post?

Thanks!

Comment: are you making cross domain requests ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
success: Success, 
error: Fail
```

You are invocating your callback functions, whereas you should be declaring them as references.

Also, the `error` callback is not passed an exception, it is passed the following three parameters.

jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown

Comment: How can I have it call a function on error or is there a way to redirect to a div in the app? if so how would I go about doing that?